# Why isn't my tank showing up?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've drawn a tile map:

http://www.exeneva.com/html5/movingTankExample/

Here's my startup code:

```
function startUp() {
  drawScreen();   
  // Draw the tank
  context.drawImage(tileSheet, tankSourceX, tankSourceY, tileWidth, tileHeight, tankX, tankY, tileWidth, tileHeight);
}
```

drawScreen() draws the tile map. I want to draw the tank after the tile map, but without putting it in drawScreen() because I want to animate and move the tank later on (without having to call drawScreen() again.

Why doesn't my tank show up?

Comment: You have to call `drawScreen()` again anyway because when the tank moves, it's previous location must be invalidated and redrawn.

Comment: I guess that's where I'm confused. I have to call drawScreen() to render the tank the first time, but then suppose I want to move it without the movement being choppy. Does that mean set an interval for drawScreen() to constantly render and then have the tank coordinates change during that interval?

Comment: For a small map like this, why not draw the whole map `everytime before updating the tank co-ordinates`? It will make things easier. In large games, only selected parts are re-drawn. But you don't need it.

Comment: @YangPulse There must be an `update` function which gets called every loop. It will update the co-ordinates of each movable object. After updating, call `drawScreen()` to draw the map, then draw other objects, farthest first.

Comment: Okay, I've put the drawing back into drawScreen(), but now the tank still isn't showing up.

Comment: Please verify `tankSourceX, tankSourceY, tileWidth, tileHeight, tankX, tankY, tileWidth, tileHeight` all have valid values.

Comment: Yes, they do. They're defined before startUp()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gessing you don't read the link I've passed you on your last answer and took the aprouch of the other guy with seemed easiest. tisk, tisk...

Anyway, to solve this, you will have to draw your tank inside the `drawScreen()` method as before, but you will have to call the animation function of the tank from inside the key moviment events. This way, the tank will draw stopped when not moving and draw animated when moving as your original question.

**Edit:**

I've got your entire code now on my machine and here are the steps to solve your problem, since I've gave you many hints, now I'll give you the code as you want:

1- The code responsible for the initialization of the animation and select the frame of the animation to be shown is inverted. The counter `frameIndex` need to be initialized before the `tankSourceX` and `tankSourceY`:

```
// Counter to keep track of the current index of animationFrames
var frameIndex = 0;
// Tank tiles
var tankSourceX = Math.floor(animationFrames[frameIndex] % tilesPerRow) * tileWidth;
var tankSourceY = Math.floor(animationFrames[frameIndex] / tilesPerRow) * tileHeight;
```

2- Place theses variables that define the frame inside the animation function, whre you change the animation frame, so the `frameIndex` changes the `tankSourceX` and `tankSourceY` values:

```
function animateMovement() { 
    // Animation frames
    frameIndex += 1;
    if (frameIndex == animationFrames.length) {
        frameIndex = 0;
    }
tankSourceX = Math.floor(animationFrames[frameIndex] % tilesPerRow) * tileWidth;
tankSourceY = Math.floor(animationFrames[frameIndex] / tilesPerRow) * tileHeight; 
}
```

3- Your drawing and animation function can be called by your event handlers or by a interval like on the begining:

```
var animateInterval = setInterval(animateMoviment, 200);
var drawingInterval = setInterval(drawScreen, 200);
```

4- Initialize a variable as the tank state:

```
var tankState = "stopped";
```

5- On the animation function, put a check for this variable to change the frames:

```
function animateMovement() { 
    if (tankState == "moving") {
        // Animation frames
        frameIndex += 1;
        if (frameIndex == animationFrames.length) {
            frameIndex = 0;
        }
        tankSourceX = Math.floor(animationFrames[frameIndex] % tilesPerRow) * tileWidth;
        tankSourceY = Math.floor(animationFrames[frameIndex] / tilesPerRow) * tileHeight; 
    }
}
```

6- Change your event handlers to set the `tankState` as `moving`:

```
e = e?e:window.event;
tankState = "moving";
...
```

7- Reset the tankState on the keyup event:

```
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    tankMoveX = 0;
    tankMoveY = 0;
    tankState = "stopped";
}
```

Off course you can call the animate and draw functions on the key event handlers and eliminate the intervals, but this way you can add more animations to be runned on the same function that do not wait for the players input, like NPC's (non plaing characters).

Comment: I tried the other way, but I've never constructed a finite state machine before and couldn't get something working :/

Comment: You seem scared with the therm and doesn't want to read a 2 page tut, but its a simple task. All you have to do is create a variable to store the tank state as a string or number and add an if statement on the animation function to only animate the frames when the state is moving.

Comment: I have something similar to that in my current implementation if you check my code. The tank will only move and animate when an arrow key is pressed. Right now my problem is getting the tank to show up.

Comment: One more time, you will have to draw the tank inside the `drawScreen()` function, below the map rendering. What is happening probably is that the map is rendered over your tank. Remove the calls to render the tank from the movement functions and call the animate function (without the rendering, just with the frame change) instead.

Comment: The drawing of the tank was moved back to drawScreen() after the first comment on here. It's also drawn after the map. Did you look at my code?

Comment: Thank you very much! But now there's another problem - the old animation frames don't disappear. You can test it at the link by pressing the down arrow.

Comment: Wow! I think understand this, and finite state machines, much better now!

Comment: This is why you're drawing the tank on the animation function, what is not needed.

Comment: A plus: next time, pay attention to the details and read the links people post. Don't come here willing to get ready to go code. With my hints you could have resolved this on the first post, that you accepted the solution of the other guy because he gave you the code to copy ans paste. Best regards.

Comment: I did read the link, but I didn't entirely understand how to implement it. However, thanks to what you've posted above, it makes a lot more sense now - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the call `context.drawImage(tileSheet, ...` you should pass the **tank image** instead of `tileSheet` which I guess is the map itself.

Comment: That's actually wrong, because the tank is part of the tile sheet :/

Comment: Can you upload the `tileSheet` image for me to see? I am trying to understand what you are doing. You may use [TinyPic](http://tinypic.com/).